# Wordpress - 2 Installation in root and subfolder in same Domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, installation

straight to the scenario:
- i had a wordpress site in my domain.de/develop
- and a wordpress site in root domain.de
I moved the the root one to 'story' and the 'develop' to the root.

The root one works fine.
Now i've got a problem with the story one, the redirect of the articles does not work.

I've changed the siteurl (database->wp_options) and had changed my .htaccess in the 'story' folder (correct?):

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler x-httpd-php7.0
</FilesMatch>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I though maybe the RewriteBase is corrput, so I changed it to:
    RewriteBase /story

The result is the same: when calling the WP Install from subfolder, it says "page cannot be found". after calling an article, it will be redirected to the root one and say "page not found"
e.g.: http://mydomain.de/story/ -> result: the 2nd wordpress with "page not found".
clicking an article, e.g.: http://mydomain.de/story/category/storyline/2016/04/24/durchatmen/ -> redirects to the root-wp and says "Nothing found".

i did all the research in the web and here on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work.

all i want to do is to get the wp-install from the subdirectory working again.
Logging in as administrator just works fine. but i can't accesss the page content itself.

Answer (score 0):

Once logged into admin dashboard, go to settings/permalinks and re-save permalinks.

If that doesn't fix your problem. Download the search and replace script from https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ and run that to fix all serialized urls...

I'm assuming you would search for domain.de/develop and replace with domain.de/story if I understood that correctly.

Comment: now it's somehow broken, it gives me an error 500 :-(

Comment: Which method did you use? Might want to set your htaccess file back to default wordpress htaccess. https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: okay, fixed it back. 

i've noticed this error:

i used re-save permalinks and took the wp .htaccess. but still same problem.
i've noticed this one:

Warning: is_writable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/web194/html/:/var/www/web194/phptmp/:/var/www/web194/files/:/var/www/web194/atd/:/usr/share/php/:/opt/php/)